# Event ID:8356,8357

Tags: 2016

I have Intranet SharePoint 2016 Farm and it is running in Port 80 on 2 WFE Servers, Since last few days I observe that Intranet portal stop working and found below logs in Event Viewers

SharePoint booted. Process Name: [w3wp] App Pool: [SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool],
Process ID: [0x21AC], App Domain Name and ID [/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/SecurityTokenServiceApplication-1-026930262],[2],
Command Line [c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe -ap "SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool" -v "v4.0" -l "webengine4.dll" -a \.\pipe\i91bbf9c-6cac-4bc1-ba44-4e9521330548 -h
"C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool\SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool.config" -w "" -m 0]

CPU Spike from [‎2022‎-‎07‎-‎19T10:35:25.026595400Z] to [‎2022‎-‎07‎-‎19T10:35:27.057859300Z]

SharePoint booted. Process Name: [w3wp] App Pool: [SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool], Process ID: [0x21AC],
App Domain Name and ID [/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/SecurityTokenServiceApplication-1-14009930262],[2],
Command Line [c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe -ap "SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool" -v "v4.0" -l "webengine4.dll" -a \.\pipe\iisipmac-4bc1-ba44-4e9521330548 -h
"C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool\SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool.config" -w "" -m 0]

SharePoint booted. Process Name: [OWSTIMER] App Pool: [N/A], Process ID: [0x2D74], App Domain Name and ID [DefaultDomain],[1],
Command Line ["C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\BIN\OWSTIMER.EXE"]

Event ID:8356,8357

Answer (score 0):

Best troubleshooter for your problem:

Run the `SharePoint Configuration Wizard`

Log into server as an admin:

On the server click:

`Start ->Programs ->Microsoft Office Server -> SharePoint Product and technoligies` configuration wizard.